# How do I draw a transparent or semi-transparent rectangle on top of an opaque one in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, render, sdl-2, rect

Here's my code to draw `SDL_Rect` objects `rect` and `rect2`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(){
    SDL_Window *window=     SDL_CreateWindow("Test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if(window == 0)
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

    SDL_Renderer *renderer= SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    if(renderer == NULL)
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.x=     100;
    rect.y=     100;
    rect.w=     100;
    rect.h=     100;

    SDL_Rect rect2;
    rect2.x=    150;
    rect2.y=    150;
    rect2.w=    100;
    rect2.h=    100;

    while(true){
        Uint8 r,g,b,a;

        r=  32;
        g=  32;
        b=  32;
        a=  255;
        if(SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a) == -1)
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        if(SDL_RenderClear(renderer) == -1)
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

        r=  255;
        g=  255;
        b=  255;
        a=  255;
        if(SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a) == -1)
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        if(SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect) == -1)
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

        r=  100;
        g=  100;
        b=  100;
        a=  0;
        if(SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, a) == -1)
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        if(SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect2) == -1)
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While I can draw `rect` to `SDL_Renderer` object `renderer` just fine, if I add `rect2` it is always opaque, blocking view of `rect`. Even though I set `rect2`'s alpha to 0, it still shows up opaque, blocking `rect` from view.

How do I fix this so `rect2` is more transparent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDL2: Generate fully transparent texture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241974/sdl2-generate-fully-transparent-texture)

Answer (score 12):

All you need to do is call
`SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);`
after creating your renderer to enable alpha blending with RenderDraw functions. ([SDL documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode))