# Transparency issue: SDL_SetTextureBlendMode

Tags: c++, sdl

I have this PNG file that has a transparent background. 
[Snippet of transparent background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKZEU.png)

I set it to **surface** then to **tex** :

```
SDL_Texture* m_Tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
```

And I want this texture to have a blinking effect so I'm passing it to **setTextureBlendMode** function

```
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(tex, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
Uint8 m_Alpha = 255;
```

I will use the **m_Alpha** for the blinking purpose. I will activate the  blinking by pressing a particular button.
And it is working fine. But Why is the background of my texture not transparent anymore after I turn it back to **SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE**:

```
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(tex, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
```

[Snippet of not transparent anymore after BLENDMODE_NONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czV1Y.png)

Is there a way to make my texture's background transparent again?
I mean, after researching enough, I can't seem to find a way except the **SDL_SetColorKey**.
But the SDL_SetColorKey needs the loaded surface again. It only means that I will set the PNG file again on **surface**, then on **tex**. I think it's not ideal to do this everytime I want the **tex** to stop blinking. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(tex, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);`
To render textures with Alpha != 1, you will need some blend mode.

In blend mode, you are describing to the system How you want to merge the background color with the foreground color.

You can have a basic idea from this thread.
[SDL2: Generate fully transparent texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241974/sdl2-generate-fully-transparent-texture)